# How to close connection immediately after finishing download with aria2c?

Tags: download, bittorrent, seed, torrent, aria2

Occasionally, I will leave an aria2c connection seeding after it has finished downloading, and then hop on a network which *doesn't like* me seeding.

I'd like to immediately close the connection after I finishing downloading, preventing me from ever seeding. How can I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Note, that the general opinion of the torrent community is that you should seed for at least the amount of the size of the file you downloaded. You can do this by providing the `seed-ratio=1.0` option:

However, this can be done by providing the `seed-time=0` option. It will immediately stop it from seeding after the download is complete:

```sh
aria2c --seed-time=0 path-to-torrent-file.torrent
```

***Note that**, it'll still seed the downloaded data during the download so some seeding may still occur.*

Comment: I'm in total agreement with seeding for at least the size of the file, this question was just asked as a precautionary to avoid tracking on certain networks. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Can you mark this as a selected answer if it meets your needs.